# Prompt user a warning before completing a API Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, api-design

Here is the use-case:

> User calls an API. API discovers that it is overwriting something
>   previously saved. To get ahead and complete, user need to say 'yes, go
>   ahead and overwrite' or 'no, don't overwrite'. So basically need a way
>   to send back the response and get the request of user's choice and
>   then continue with the operation.

My concerns are:

- What is the best practice to do so?
- If I adjourn the service and return the response as choice needed. Do I need to fire the same API after the user entered the choice?

I am using Nodejs/Express and Angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Each API request should probably be stateless.  To do that, you add an option to your API that instructs what the server should do if an overwrite would occur.  The client could specify either to overwrite if exists or don't overwrite and return status that data already exists.

It is then up to the client if it will then prompt the user and make a second API call asking for the overwrite.  This is client behavior, not server policy.

If the client first sends `don't overwite` and then after prompting makes a second API call asking to overwrite, then the server will likely have to rerun the API call from scratch.  It is implementation specific whether anything can be temporarily cached from the first request to improve the performance of the second request.  That's an implementation choice on the server, the same as any other performance-improving caching.

Comment: This is how I'd do it. A request without the "overwrite" flag but that would actually be an overwrite returns 405, and the client interprets that as "must be data there already, need to ask user to explicitly overwrite".

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to develop API then you can either:

1. Create another API to check whether the data exist; and then
2. Proceed with the API after confirming with the user

or:

Make another flag in the API like 'canOverwrite' and confirm with user before calling the API whether the data can be overwritten if exist.

Using websockets instead of HTTP calls would also give you flexibility in emitting confirmations (but may not be applicable on AngularJS).

Comment: Checking if the data exists in one API call and then making a decision based on that in the client is a race condition.  The check and then apply overwrite logic needs to be an atomic operation on the server to avoid race conditions with some other API request changing whether the data exists.

Comment: @j_k like pointed out in below ans. what if there is a data change in between the verify API and proceed with the operation api

Comment: If the API deals with transactional data you need to have a timestamp associated with verifying api and update Pai

Comment: @SiddharthSrivastva, When you read data you also have to take the timestamp (lastupdatedTime) of the data. This need to be used when you verify the data. If the data gets modified by another user then the timestamp passed through the verifying API and the timestamp in the table will not match.

Comment: @j_k let me test this out. Will let you know soon

Answer (score 0):

As @jfriend00 mentioned above, REST apis are supposed to be stateless. But you could achieve this through your backend nodeJs code. Actually it's an illusion of state but it's really not.

So you would have two endpoints like

1. **/data/verify**

   This would just check if the data is present in the database and send a true or false to the UI
2. **/data/add**

   Now if the user wants to overwrite and clicks the 'OVERWRITE' button or something on the UI, send a request to this endpoint which would overwrite the data.

If the the user doesn't want to overwrite, don't call the add endpoint.

Comment: The problem with this is that someone else could have added data between verifying and adding. The add endpoint still needs to behave correctly in this case, not just assume that if it's being called then whatever's there should be overwritten. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216592/prompt-user-a-warning-before-completing-a-api-nodejs/38216707#comment63856612_38216707 on the other answer that suggested this.

Comment: Good point. May be in the verify api, a flag could be set in the data that would lock the data for like a specified time? And the subsequent verify calls would just check the lockState and exit if its locked. That way, the race condition could be avoided.

Comment: So... stateful? And not just the illusion of it. That would work, but it isn't very RESTful!

Comment: `/data/verify` is subject to race conditions since the data can change between the time the result is returned and the client makes some decision based on it.  This is the same reason that `fs.existsSync(path)` is being deprecated.  There's no safe way to use it without being subject to race conditions.  Instead, you tell the server the operation you want to do and you tell it what to do if the data already exists and the server can then implement an atomic check and operation.  Unless you have stateful locks, only the server can implement an atomic operation.